# Speeding up take with numba?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, numba

Is it possible to speed up np.take using numba?

Here is my attempt, but it is a lot slower. I can't use nopython mode as it does not like the np.empty_like command.

```
import numba
import numpy as np
from timer import Timer    

def take( x, indices ):
    result = np.empty_like( indices, dtype=x.dtype )    
    for i in range( len( indices ) ):
        result[i] = x[ indices[ i ] ]
    return result

jtake = numba.jit("f4[:](f4[:],i4[:])" )( take )

if __name__=='__main__':

    N = 100000
    m = 100
    idx = np.random.random_integers( 0, N, m )
    x = np.random.randn( N )

    num_tests=10000

    with Timer( 'take' ):
        for i in range( num_tests ):    
            r0 = take( x, idx )

    with Timer( 'Numba take' ):
        for i in range( num_tests ):    
            r1 = jtake( x, idx )                

    with Timer( 'Numpy.take' ):
        for i in range( num_tests ):
            r2 = x.take( idx )
```

Which has results:

```
Beginning take
take took 2.46 seconds
Beginning Numba take
Numba take took 1.11 seconds
Beginning Numpy.take
Numpy.take took 0.04 seconds
```

Comment: "Is it possible to speed up np.take using numba?" I doubt that you can.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is no.

Numba will not act on compiled functions such as `np.take()` or the array methods that work with fancy indexing, which is the basis for your algorithm. Numba acts on the interpreted part of your code.

Your `take()` function probably has more overhead than NumPy's and Numba has improved the for loops (interpreted).

With NumPy > 1.9 your code should get closer to NumPy's take since your algorithm is based on fancy indexing and [they improved the fancy indexing efficiency](http://sourceforge.net/projects/numpy/files/NumPy/1.9.0/) to the level of `np.take()`.